# How to add a lattice extension to an existing fence

Tags: woodworking, fence, carpentry

I would like to put an 18" lattice extension onto an existing 4' fence (see awesome photoshopping skillz below), needing approx 15 copies, each being 8' spans. Questions I have are:

- Best (strength and aesthetics) way to connect onto existing posts?

I am aware my question is related [this](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/141185/how-to-secure-privacy-lattice-to-top-of-existing-fence-gate) question except that I'm not looking to repair existing lattice, nor am I attaching lattice to a gate or something that will be moved. My posts are 4x4s concreted into the ground, so neither would I want to try to rebuild the whole fence.

My fence is built with Strongties [FB24](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Simpson-Strong-Tie-FB-ZMAX-Galvanized-Fence-Rail-Bracket-for-2x4-Nominal-Lumber-FB24Z/100375311?source=shoppingads&locale=en-US&pla&mtc=SHOPPING-BF-CDP-GGL-D22-022_014_METAL_PRDCT-NA-NA-NA-PMAX-NA-NA-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NEW-PMAX&cm_mmc=SHOPPING-BF-CDP-GGL-D22-022_014_METAL_PRDCT-NA-NA-NA-PMAX-NA-NA-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NEW-PMAX-71700000099246737--&gclid=CjwKCAjwgqejBhBAEiwAuWHioAxLriX1tssZsv0EGXL1YeFxt7_Y2cVsrNSHvPsi9K2c_MkGMPphthoCCjIQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds#overlay) connecting 8 ft 2x4s to the 4x4 posts. A 2x4 is also used as a trim piece. See pictures below. Ideally, I would not want to modify any of this stuff.

- Best (cheapest and/or fastest) way to source the lattice. I'm looking for a completely closed weave, which doesnt leave many off-the-shelf options.

I see a lot of pre-made lattice like [this](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Veranda-4-ft-x-8-ft-Sierra-Cedar-Garden-Vinyl-Lattice-73004021/202082682) that are even [pre-framed](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Barrette-Outdoor-Living-4-ft-x-8-ft-California-Redwood-Privacy-Diamond-Vinyl-Lattice-Framed-73004040/202847976). However, I would like to have a completely closed weave (like [this](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Mendocino-Forest-Products-0-63-in-x-12-in-x-8-ft-Redwood-Select-Common-Triple-Weave-Privacy-Lattice-14495/205813697)).  I am considering the suggested solution of using a shade sail backing fabric from this [question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/249094/what-can-i-add-to-make-small-gap-privacy-lattice-more-private), but would prefer the three-layer closed-weave wood solution if it is not cost/time prohibitive.

Does anyone have experience taking a pre-framed lattice panel and modifying it?

- Choice of wood (species/treated) and finishes to match the existing weathered fence.

Should I make everything (lattice strips and frame) of treated lumber? Any concerns with potentially thickness planing treated lumber? It doesnt sound super healthy...

[image: Concept]
[image: construction]

Comment: do you need a permit for that

Comment: aesthetics is not good

Comment: Use the same material as the rest of the fence. As for planing pressure treated, you should have reasonable dust collection any time you use a planer, and when that is present it really isn't worse than any other PT carpentry for health risk

Comment: Given that your fence is painted or stained, I'd be tempted to just screw/bolt a long 2x4 to each post, and fasten your lattice to the part of the 2x4 that sticks up.  Then paint/stain it all to match (although you might have to refinish the fence while you're at it).

Answer (score 1):

To extend your 4x4 posts, use the same material and join them with a big dowel.  I would say 1 to 1.5" in diameter would do the job.  Aligning the posts perfectly won't be easy given the post themselves are not uniformly cut.  You might not like the look of it as the joint will be visible.

For the lattice, I think making it would be easier than modifying a premade one.  I don't think you need treated lumber because it doesn't touch the ground. Using cedar or redwood would be good enough.  If you have a table saw, you can cut strips from 2-by-X and don't really need to use a thickness planner.